# SQLite auto increase a non-primary key

Tags: sqlite

I have a table which has one primary key integer:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (ID INTEGER PRIMARYKEY,ZID INTEGER)
```

That zid integer field that must be incremented from the previous one found in the database.

I could do something like that:

```
INSERT INTO TBL (zid) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(zid) + 1 FROM TBL));
```

However, the value of that integer field will, at some point, reset to zero. Therefore I want to increment from the last entry, not necessarily the maximum in the entire table.

How can I do that? A trigger?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not switch `zid` and `id`. The behaviour you are asking for is delivered by `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. In fact, what you want is `zid` to act as an ordinary primary key. What do you want from `ID`? Why have two??

Comment: @MrGumble I need two, because the zid's value may not be unique, it depends on other fields in the table.

Comment: You'd have to provide an example with data; include when (if applicable) `zid` is not used, when `zid` defaults to 0, when `zid` is 1, and when `zid` is set to +1. Just make up some columns of `ID`, `zid`, and `a`. `zid` is set to +1 if a new row is inserted with a value of `a` that already exists?

Answer (score -1):

how about a query like:
`SELECT zid + 1 FROM TBL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

with this select query you will only get the value from the last line (+1)

Comment: I would say your query would lead to the same result as OP's; and it isn't safeguarded against the `zid` being reset to 0 (whatever that means).

Comment: no thats not correct. my query takes the zid value from the last inserted row. his query takes the maximum value from all rows of the table.